# Do I need to set up public files directory for multi-sites differently?

Tags: multi-sites, 9, security

I had some Drupal installations which I merged into a multi-site installation.

When they were single installations, I created a *files* in the root directory and set the system permissions for the directory and its content to 755. When I ran the security review, I got no errors.

Now I set up them as multi-site; the *files* directory is still in the root folder, and inside there also the *site1*, *site2*, *site3* directories used from the single sites. When I set the system permissions to 755 and run the security review, I get an error that about some files in my public files directory which are writeable by the server.

[image]

Those files have been always writeable by the server. Otherwise, CSS/JavaScript aggregation and file uploading wouldn't work.

When I set the *files* folder in the root directory as well as *site1*, *site2*, *site3* to 555, the security review didn't report anything, but I got an error message from the Drupal status report because the public file system is not writeable from the server.

Do I need to set up the public files directory for multi-sites differently?

Comment: have you tried chmod -R 755 files/site1 files/site2 ... ?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes I did, but I didn't read very attentive. My files folder has 555 and the site1, site2, site3 have 755 -R. And it works like expected, as it spares out the own public folder. So, if I rund a security review in the backend of site 1, I still get the error. Because It tells me in the details, that it also found the public folders of site 2 and site3, which are also 755. So it seems to throw the error because there are other directories as well, that don't belong to this installation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the question: no you do not need to set up those directories differently. The webserver obviously needs write access there for storing files. If the security_review module has a problem with the dirs of the other sites then it is probably a bug in that module.

Anyhow: first click on details, maybe you find out more information there.

Then I had a look at the code, this is the method that detects the error:

https://git.drupalcode.org/project/security_review/-/blob/8.x-1.x/src/Checks/FilePermissions.php#L48

It also tries to write a file in its own module directory (which it does not communicate to the user -> not nice), so have a look into there and see if there is a file called "file_write_test[...]" or if there is a warning inside "IGNOREME.txt". If that is the case you need to remove write access to the modules directories for the webserver user (usually www-data)